# Where do I enter PPOE user and password over ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, pppoe

I have an internet connection by PPOE over **ethernet cable** (not phone), I understand that "DSL" is for phone line.

I am not sure where to enter the PPOE user/pass that my provider gave me, if I select "Ethernet" connection then I get no prompt for PPOE user / pass.

[image]

Comment: Select `DSL` and then you will see it.

Comment: I fixed it, I was not supposed to type a "service" name next to user/password. I cleared it and then it connected. Not very intuitive :)

Answer (score 0):

I was supposed to select DSL for ppoe over ethernet cable and with my provider it didn't connect unless I cleared the **[service]** name box next to user/password.